# Making laptop "less" secure via passwordless login using some "dongle" or other thingie

Tags: linux, security

The modern days requires us to use super-strong passwords like: `u"=8-,vR'X?!}$!q` It's briliant indeed, but if we talk only about local access (for remote it's for sure required) all such benefits ends, when you need to go to restroom or kitchen and then log in again.

The laptop is in secure environment, where noone will attempt physical login. And IIUC if it's not the case, even `u"=8-,vR'X?!}$!q` will not help against physical attacks like spraying rams with nitrogen and dumping crypt luks keys.

So I actually don't need `u"=8-,vR'X?!}$!q` "security" for on-site login. What I need is to be able to lock session somehow and unlock it quickly not to waste 150x times a day typing `u"=8-,vR'X?!}$!q`. I found blueproximity project to log in and out using bluetooth device proximity, but that's severely outdated and it does not work either plus according to bugs it leaks. Is there any other way how to achieve similar stuff? Like creating some sort of flashdisc which unlocks session when plugged in or anything similar?

Comment: Use a fingerprint reader?

Comment: Lenovo P52, too new to be working on linux. Tried that. But if you can show me, how to make that working, please do.

Answer (score 2):

There are screenlockers that can lock/unlock automatically when they sense a bluetooth device (typically, you phone) within range. After that it all depends if the restroom is sufficiently far from your desk...

Where I work the PCs have a smartcard reader, we don't use passwords but a PIN for the smartcard.

You can also replace the screenlocker by another program that doesn't use the password.

PS: `u"=8-,vR'X?!}$!q` isn't secure, it's a password you will always find written on paper. A reasonable (16+ characters, mostly letters) password is both secure and not that hard/long to type in.

Comment: +1 for the PS .

Comment: Damn guys, you're not up-to-date with Microsoft recommendations, or what? Yep, sure. This is not secure because of human-reasons. But these nonsense passwords are still required everywhere and has to be recreated each month or 2 or 3. But you cannot compete with company insecurity team knowledge.

Comment: Any recommendation for such sw, which can work with smartcard reader / usb?

Comment: If the passwords are enforced by company policy, then such software must be approved/procured by company officlals. Trying to shortcircuit their policies is putting your job at risk.

Comment: **Damn guys, you're not up-to-date with Microsoft recommendations, or what?** URL? The ones I found say almost the opposite: [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/admin/misc/password-policy-recommendations?view=o365-worldwide) and [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Microsoft_Password_Guidance-1.pdf).

Comment: @xenoid I'm aware of the fact that microsoft changed this stragety *this* year. It's less than 5 months IIRC, while their recommendations were known to be retarded 5 years ago at least. And you need to understand, that this stuff has momentum. There will be hordes of M$ security "experts" enforcing "strong" passwords and their regular changes by users. We have whole retarded team doing exactly that. OK I admit, that I was knowingly not 100% accurate, but from the formulation you can see that was intended as a joke. But jokes aside,M$ recommendations endangered security of users, and still will